# devices has required level of API . but unable to install App

Tags: android, installation

I am new to the android  App developing . My Android phone runs on 4.0.3
 i an developing  app with miniSDk 4.0(API 14) and TargetSDK 4.4(API 20) .but the App  not supported for my device. help me

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android  {

compileSdkVersion 20
buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.appspace.arudinoblue"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 20
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),    'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

  dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
 }
```

Comment: compileSdkVersion 14

Comment: Can you please elaborate 'not supported'? Is it not debugable when you play from android studio? Or is it published to app store but you can't install it?